# Blender Icon in the main menu not working when i clicking

Tags: blender

Blender icon in main menu,when i clicked it nothing happend.
but i launch via terminal it is opening.
I'm tried with .desktop file but its also confusing about path of exec= and icon=

```
Exec=blender %f
Icon=${SNAP}/blender.svg
```

The above mentioned in snap folder ,i confused whether i create a .desktop file in .local or anything?

Comment: This question needs to be more focused. We need to know what you even mean. What Blender icon, what main menu, clicking what, and what are you even trying to acheive?

Comment: @AlexFullinator it looks like OP needs help making a .desktop file for Blender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a .desktop file appear in your shell and app menus, you have to put it  in `~/.local/share/applications`, with execute permissions.

Comment: I done it yesterday but it disappeared after a night